# Failed to load the native TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

When I import `tensorflow` into Python. I have a error. I use pip.
I tried to uninstall `tensorflow` but the error persists. I don't understand
when I try `pip uninstall tensorflow` i have 
  Skipping tensorflow as it is not installed.
and then :

> > > import tensorflow
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
> > >               from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> > >             File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
> > >               _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
> > >             File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
> > >               _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
> > >             File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
> > >               return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
> > >             File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
> > >               return _load(spec)
> > >           ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
> > >             Referenced from: /Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
> > >             Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
> > >            in /Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/categorisation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

I didn't find the solution on the site https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

Answer (score 0):

First try to upgrade `pip version` via the

'`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`' command.

Then try to remove `TensorFlow`

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Hope it helps.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried and "Requirement already up-to-date"